# In Java is it possible to check at runtime on which subclass a method was called?

Tags: java

```
interface Y {
 void search(String name);
}
class A implements Y {
  void search(String name) {
     //Is it possible to say: "If I was called from class B then do a search("B");
  }
}

class B extends A {
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      B b = new B();
      b.search();
    }
}
```

Given the above code is it possible to reason in superclass which subclass was used for calling a method?

The reason I want to do this is because the code in Search is very similar for all Subclasses, the only thing that changes is the Classname, so I thought there is no need to Override in each subclass. I have updated the code to reflect this. Please let me know if there is a better way of doing it/

Comment: you could override `search` in `class B`

Comment: Can you explain why you need this? A superclass should not be concerned about its subclasses. The subclass should handle it himself, like @jhamon suggests.

Comment: As @cvesters points out, the idiomatic way to solve this is by letting `B` override `search`. If you really want to, you can of course do `if (this instanceof B) { ... }` inside `A::search`.

Comment: @Shakur what do you mean by `the only thing that changes is the Classname`?

Comment: @jhamon based on the subclass classname Im doing a different search

Comment: "based on the subclass classname Im doing a different search" That's *exactly* what subclassing is for. Just override the method in the subclass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `this.getClass()` inside your `search` method will give you the concrete class of the current instance.

For example:

```
class Example
{
    static class A {
        public void search() {
            System.out.println(getClass());
        }
    }

    static class B extends A {}

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        new A().search();
        new B().search();
    }
}
```

outputs

```
class Example$A
class Example$B
```

Comment: That's correct but OP should think about what behaviour is expected if he creates a class `C` extending `B`. `search("B")` or `search("C")`. Of course, there should be no issue if he si sure those would not be extended

Comment: @jhamon I agree: overriding the method is clearly the correct approach. This merely provides an answer to what the OP asked for, which is to determine the class on which the method was invoked.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to do it is to override the method in each subclass.

```
interface Y {
    void search();
}

class A implements Y {
    public void search(){
        search("A");
    }

    protected void search(String name) {
        // implement your searching algoithm here
    }
}


class B extends A {
    public void search(){
        search("B");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.search();
    }
}
```

That's the way inheritance is suppose to works. A super class should not know its subclasses.
And, in case you extends your class `B`, you can easily either:

-Keep the same behaviour as B:

```
class C extends B {
    // do nothing, when calling search, it calls the method implemented in B
}
```

-Change the behaviour to search for `"C"`

```
class C extends B {
    public void search(){
        search("C"); // or search("whateveryouwant")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply override the method in class B. 
The other way could be to write the `search()` method as

```
 void search() {
    if (this.getClass().equals(B.class)) {
        //The logic for B
    } else if (this.getClass().equals(A.class)) {
        //The logic for A
    }
}
```

You have to provide the fully qualified name for the class.

Comment: Overriding the method in `B` is cleaner than the second method. And your second method could be a bit less dirty is you use `this instanceof B`

Comment: Calling toString() and doing a string comparison is a bit overkill.  `this.getClass() == B.class` or as @jhamon said  `this instanceof B` would be better.

Comment: Now it's plain wrong. A `String` will never `equals` a `Class`. Why don't you use `instanceof` as suggested by @jhamon?

Answer (score 0):

Better follow template pattern.

```
interface Y {
 void search(String name);
}

abstract class AbstractionTemplate implements Y{

    @Override
    public void search(String name) {
      //a lot of code.
        System.out.println("common stuff start");
        doImplspecificStuffOnly();
        System.out.println("common stuff end");
      //a lot of code.

    }

    abstract void doImplspecificStuffOnly();

}

class A extends  AbstractionTemplate{

  @Override
  void doImplspecificStuffOnly() {
     System.out.println("a's stuff");
  }
}

class B extends A {
     @Override
      void doImplspecificStuffOnly() {
         System.out.println("B's stuff");
      }

}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      B b = new B();
      b.search("hey");
    }
}
```